# Cannot install bmon using opkg under Openwrt?

Tags: openwrt, opkg

After running `opkg install bmon`, I got this error:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# opkg install bmon
Installing bmon (4.0-1) to root...
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages/bmon_4.0-1_ar71xx.ipk.
Multiple packages (libpthread and libpthread) providing same name marked HOLD or PREFER. Using latest.
Installing libncursesw (5.9-3) to root...
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/libncursesw_5.9-3_ar71xx.ipk.
Configuring iftop.
//usr/lib/opkg/info/iftop.postinst: line 4: default_postinst: not found
Collected errors:
 * check_data_file_clashes: Package libncursesw wants to install file /usr/lib/libform.so
    But that file is already provided by package  * libncurses
 * check_data_file_clashes: Package libncursesw wants to install file /usr/lib/libmenu.so
    But that file is already provided by package  * libncurses
 * check_data_file_clashes: Package libncursesw wants to install file /usr/lib/libncurses.so
    But that file is already provided by package  * libncurses
 * check_data_file_clashes: Package libncursesw wants to install file /usr/lib/libpanel.so
    But that file is already provided by package  * libncurses
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package bmon.
 * pkg_run_script: package "iftop" postinst script returned status 127.
 * opkg_configure: iftop.postinst returned 127.
```

I have searched for quite a while, but there is few info about bmon.

And this is my `opkg.conf`

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /etc/opkg.conf 
#src/gz attitude_adjustment http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/ar71xx/generic/packages
dest root /
dest ram /tmp
lists_dir ext /var/opkg-lists
option overlay_root /overlay
src/gz chaos_calmer_base http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/base
src/gz chaos_calmer_packages http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages
src/gz chaos_calmer_luci http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/luci
src/gz chaos_calmer_routing http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/routing
src/gz chaos_calmer_telephony http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/telephony
src/gz chaos_calmer_management http://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/trunk/ar71xx/generic/packages/management
```

Answer (score 1):

From the logs it seems like bmon has dependency on libncursesw which tries to install some files which were already available from libncurses.
Since both the packages has similar functionalities, you can force the installation by

> opkg --nodeps install bmon

This will install the required package but leave the dependencies.